# Cordova add multiple line in local notification

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

In cordova project with platform of ios, android using local notification plugin and it is working fine , i want to add full text content without truncate(... single row end of the line).
Following :-

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/pull/92

I want to add view like : -
"USERNAME", it's time
row 1 (product 1) PRODUCTNAME
row 2 (product 2) PRODUCTNAME

Because it gives good look to get note. Please let me know if expert has something to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to store the data either on device or on your database. 
If your doing it on device then you just need to call it accordingly. just inject the proper plugin (local or session, local will be preferred). 
I would recommend not doing this locally rather thank making doing in your database.
How i do this is i collect the GCM id and feed it to my server with the user and whenever i need to send notification i spun up my heroku and send it(automating is very easy in this process) .